# Find all triples of positive integers x, y and z such that x ≤ y ≤ z and $x^y + y^z = z^x$

Tags: number-theory

I find one solution and that is (1,1,2), but still, I cannot get any idea on a general solution to this question. Could anyone help me with that or give me some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well known that for $a>b$, if $a^b>b^a$, then we must have $(a,b)=(3,2)$ or $b=1$. In your equation, you have:
$$z^x =x^y+y^z >y^z \geqslant x^z$$

If $(z,x)=(3,2)$ then we have $2^y+y^3=9$, which clearly is not possible for positive integer $y$. Thus, we must have $x=1$. Substituting gives $y^z+1=z$. We know that $2^z>z$, so this once again forces $y=1$ and thus, $z=2$. Hence, the only solution is $(x,y,z)=(1,1,2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution is clear and helpful!